# With Angular Material tables, how to have a click event handler for a table row that ignores one column

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table, onclick, angular-material2

I have a row in my Angular Material table that I want to be clickable. The problem is that I also have an icon in the last column of the row that I also want to be clickable but handled differently. Right now, when I click on the icon, it calls both handlers and I don't want that. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Publisher">

    <!-- LastName Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.lastName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- FirstName Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.firstName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Actions -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClickDelete(row.id)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row (click)="onClickPublisher(row.id)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that when I click on the `delete` icon it doesn't call the click handler for the entire row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple things that might help:

Pass the click event along with the id into the backend code like this:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="onClickDelete($event, row.id)">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Then you can catch it in the ts. On the icon, you can try stopPropagation like this:

```
onClickDelete(e, id) {
    e.stopPropagation();
   // do stuff with the id;
}
```

On the row, one option is to check the targets class list:

```
onClickDelete(e, id) {
   if (e.target.className.includes('mat-icon-button')) {
       return;
   }
   //Do stuff with id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, i wanted to show pop up on icon click from table. Here is my workaround:

html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-button (click)="showAlert(element)">
            <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
        </button>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selectedRows(row)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

ts

...

```
public isClicked = false;
```

...

```
showAlert(action) {
    this.isClicked = true;

    //this open popup
    swal({
        //popup part
    }).then(isConfirm => {
        this.isClicked = false;
    }, (dismiss) => {
        if (dismiss === 'cancel' || dismiss === 'close') {
            this.isClicked = false;
        } 
    });
}
```

and then just check if the icon is clicked

```
selectedRows(row){
    if(!this.isClicked){
        //do what ever you want icon is not clicked
    }
}
```